# Live debug a .NET application, the !mt command just returns "Unable to resolve call target. Error = 0x80004005"

Tags: .net, windbg, sosex

When I break at:

```
framework.SendEmail(string, string, string, string)
```

and run `!mt` I get:

> Unable to resolve call target. Error = 0x80004005

What I believe should happen is the debugger should continue, then break at:

```
smtputil.SendEmail(string, string, string, string)
```

I'm using sosex.dll v4.5.0.692 on a .NET 2.0 application, with WinDbg 6.3.9600.17298

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you did not upgrade to SOSEX 4.5.0.783?

Comment: OT question: where did you get that version from? I re-downloaded the debugging tools from the Windows SDK setup, but it still is 6.3.9600.16384.

Comment: @ThomasW. Interesting. I'm not sure, I used the boostrap installer, only selected debugging tools for windows, and that's the version that appears in the title bar...

Comment: @ThomasW. I didn't realize that there was a .783 of sosex.dll, but I just upgraded it and I get the same error when trying !mt

Comment: !mt relies on some disassembly and decoding of IL behind the scenes to do its work, and I don't get it right in all cases.  If you can share an exe and instructions for how to repro, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @SteveJohnson: thank you. I hope Jace can share something.

Comment: @SteveJohnson Thanks for the reply. I don't have anything I can share publicly yet. I have tested another application and got the same results though. I may just write a test exe and see if that repros the issue. Also I emailed the address you put in the extension @ pobox.com

Comment: Maybe I'm using it wrong. My goal is to be able to let the code execute from where I am now until the next function is called. Is that what !mt is meant to do?

Comment: !mt is the (m)anaged equivalent of the "t" debugger command.  It means trace into.